# Testing Chrome DeclarativeContent PageStateMatchers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I've got a [Chrome extension](https://github.com/dheidelberger/broll-credit-copier/) that works by scraping data from a number of different websites. Since websites can be redesigned frequently, I'm trying to design some testing for the extension based mostly around loading a list of sites and seeing if the extension still gets the correct information.

The extension is a [page action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction), meaning it only runs when a user clicks its icon in the address bar. I'm also using [PageStateMatchers](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-PageStateMatcher) in the Chrome DeclarativeContent API to only make the extension clickable on certain sites or when certain CSS rules are matched.

So for my first set of tests, I'd like to check if the extension is "shown" (as Chrome calls it). Effectively, is it clickable? I'm not aware of any good way to do this. I'm using [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/) for my testing.

Any thoughts about how I might be able to do this?

Comment: AFAICT you should use your language framework (built-in or a library) to control the mouse click using predefined offsets from the top-right corner, which should be more or less predictable if you run chrome in a new empty user profile via --user-data-dir.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to more or less be the only way to do things. The extension responds to a keyboard shortcut. I'm using [robotjs](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs) to simulate a shortcut. You can also use that library to figure out the color on the screen at a given set of coordinates, so I can use that to figure out if the icon for the extension is disabled or not.